# interactive planar straight line graph in swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to draw an interactive planar straight line graph (PSLG) on a JApplet. I am using mouse-clicks to determine the vertices of the PSLG.

Here is the algorithm which I am following for drawing edges of the PSLG
1. The point where user performs a mouse-click is added as a vertex of the PSLG.
2. If he clicks a second point,an edge is directly created among the point and the previously clicked-point

Here are certain flaws which I observed due to the use of this algorithm:

1. Inability to create disjoint-planar sets like say just a line segment
2. A closed polygon is only created if the user clicks at the exact location where the start point was [Essentially, if the user clicks very close to the start point, there is no way to tell that this point is actually the start point since it appears within a certain tolerance range from the point].

I've checked out some similar questions over here and people suggest to use the **JFreeChart** library. But as far as I get, the scenario in those questions was that the points of the PSLG were already known.  I do not know whether **JFreeChart** can be used for creating interactive PSLG's

I thought about adding points and having a button which would say add edges among points,but if that's the case selecting the 2 points will still involve the proximity problem encountered in 2.

I was wondering if anybody could suggest me a better approach on how to handle this situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem #1, but for #2, you could pop up a menu on right click allowing the user to close the polygon if desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GraphPanel`](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) could be adapted to this task, although it might benefit from a more advanced [edge model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight-line_graph) for faster searching. Also consider [`JGraph`](http://www.jgraph.com/).