# Graph as a Java Collection

Tags: java, collections, graph

I'm trying to implement a Graph with implements a Collection.
Like,

```
Graph is a Set of Vertices, Set of Edges
```

But couldn't get the exact implementation

Somebody outline the idea..

Comment: Some examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10047021/230513).

Comment: hope this previous post on graph representation help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737627/java-how-to-represent-graphs

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Graph {
    private Set<Vertex> nodes;
    private Set<Edge> edges;
}
```

If you want to look at more "serious" implementation of graph check [jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html)
library.

You can find basic tutorial [here](http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf)